# Chrome extension help

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to notify an user using Chrome browser. I need something powerful like changing the Chrome skin colour, highlighting things or at the least like this extension putting an icon on the address bar https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jhejngphiacapbgllhagbpdkkdieeaej

Can someone please help?

Edit:

Q1, can I change the theme when a new tab or new chrome window is open? Like the change in incognito mode?

Q2, How do I put an image on the address bar like flag fox?

Comment: Is there anything specific you need help with? Yes we can help but we need a question before we can answer it.

Comment: I hope the edit clarifies things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A1: No you cannot. The user must agree to changing their theme. Imagine if an extension switched your theme to show "inappropriate" content.

A2: Use page actions. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction